# ASP.NET code performance vs Console App

Tags: asp.net, .net, multithreading, performance, memory

I have code that processes some data (spatial data manipulation) which takes about 5 seconds to run in a console app. The same code in an ASP.NET environment takes 50 seconds to run.

I have set the option in Visual Studio (Community) to use the 64-bit version of IIS Express, and I am targeting the x64 platform in the web app's build configuration.

The processing consumes about 600MB of RAM, so it's not an extraordinary amount.

If it's a threading issue: when I run `System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workers, out completions)` in my WebApi Controller (that runs the code) I get 32767 workers and 1000 completions.

Is there any way I can get this to run at a similar performance as the console app?

The code the I am running is this: https://github.com/capesean/TopologyPreservingSimplifier/blob/master/TopologyPreservingSimplifier/Utilities.cs

I am passing in about 10 geometries into the `SimplifyAndReduce` function. The following line (#54) is where most of the processing occurs:

```
return new NetTopologySuite.Operation.Union.UnaryUnionOp(shapes).Union();
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way, what is the code? How are you timing it? In situations like this, start by asking, what is the difference? Keep an open mind. Without a working example that recreates the problem you won't be able to get a definitive answer. Someone might offer speculation that happens to be right in your scenario but only you will be able to test it.

Comment: Just because the thread pool exists and it supports concurrent activity, it doesn't mean the code you are running is using multiple threads.

Comment: I've added some code. The `Union()` function is where the delay is happening. However, it's the same code in the console app. So presumably one environment (console) is accessing more threads/memory. I can't modify that code (external library) so it's really about whether I can get IIS to allocate the same resources, from what I can tell.